# SUM the occurrences (COUNT) of 2 table

Tags: sql-server, mysql, query, count

i have 2 databases with same columns [id, name] and many many rows.
I want to make query separatly and then make a union. This because the extremely dimension of the 2 databases.

SELECT id, count(distinct name)

FROM tabel_1

GROUP BY id

Starting with this query for both db, i would like to sum the count results based on id.

Example:

> df1  = [ [a,5], [b,10] ]
>
> df1  = [ [a,7], [b,1], [c,15] ]

---

> sum = [ [a,12], [b,11], [c,15] ]

Comment: How many rows are we talking about? "Extreme dimensions"? Chances are that the union of both results will be slow, especially when you have to calculate sums the way you describe. I'm not convinced you are approaching this correctly.

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, SUM(cnt)
FROM
    (
     SELECT id, count(distinct name) AS cnt
     FROM tabel_1
     GROUP BY id
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id, count(distinct name) AS cnt
     FROM tabel_2
     GROUP BY id
     ) T
GROUP BY id
```